# thunderbird crashes at start up

Tags: gnome, thunderbird

Upgraded to 13.04 from 12.04, but Thunderbird crashes immediately on start, also tweak tool crashes when trying to access the font menu from terminal error message is:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible)
```

any help greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Feel free to edit your own post by adding more information about the Thunderbird crash, as well as another useful information as software versions. The more information you provide, the higher the chances that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

These two issues are probably not related at all.

## Unity Tweak Tool

When Ubuntu is upgraded, 3rd party PPAs (repositories) are disabled. Maybe you're still using an old Unity Tweek Tool that is NOT compatible with Ubuntu 13.04.

Check your Unity Tweak Tool version. Open a terminal and paste this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep unity-tweak-tool
```

The latest version available at the moment of writing this is `0.0.5-0~136~raring1`. If you have an older version, go to [the official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freyja-dev/+archive/unity-tweak-tool-daily), add it again to your system and then update.

## Thunderbird

You are not providing too much information. This can be caused by several problems. These are some of the most common:

### Disk space

Check that there is disk space available. You can do that on several ways, but a very simple and quick one is by using the terminal. Launch a terminal from Unity, and run this command

```
df -h
```

You'll see one line for every mount point. If you see some mount point with a large usage (>95%) try to free some space.

### Package manager Status

The package manager status could be bad, so some packages can be mid-installed, or mid-upgraded. You can check that by issuing this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that says 0 packages for updating and such, everything is fine. Don't worry about not updated packages. You can have some not updated packages and still everything is fine.

### User profile

Maybe your Thunderbird user profile is corrupted somehow. The easiest way to test this is to create another user, login as that user, and try to run Thunderbird.

If Thunderbird is working with that user, then just simply move your old Thunderbird profile to some other location.

```
mv ~/.thunderbird ~/.thunderbird-old
```

And then try to start Thunderbird again. You will lose your configurations, though. But worry not, you can still configure it again to access your local mail, if available.

Comment: I'm actually using gnome, so I ran dpkg -l | grep gnome-tweak-tooldpkg -l | grep gnome-tweak-tool
ii  gnome-tweak-tool                            3.8.0+git20130410.577d7991-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0  all          tool to adjust advanced configuration settings for GNOME
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       114G   30G   78G  28% /

Comment: You seem to be using the [Gnome Testing PPA from Rico Tzschichholz](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing). Can you check that you still have the PPA enabled and updated to the last versions? Try removing the PPA with `ppa-purge`, maybe that PPA is the culprit.